# Using Google maps for a store locator

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, iframe

So, I built a simple store locator, spent hours trying to get it to work and finally realized that the issue was Google maps won't allow you to iframe the entire page. Is there any kind of work around for this to get it to display? Or a way to do what I'm doing without iframes?

Ideally just the map itself would be great without the rest of the page, but I can't find a way to do it with the api that doesn't require a database or some sort of data file and there are just too many store locations being changed all the time to keep up with that.

Here's what I have so far.

The markup:

```
    <%@ Page Title="HelixMix | Where To Buy" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WhereToBuy.aspx.cs" Inherits="WhereToBuy" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function reloadFrame(Map) {
            document.getElementById(Map).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectStore() {
            document.write("Please select at least one store."); // Change location on page...
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div id="Locator">
        Zip code:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" placeholder="Zip code" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="personalSpace">Which store would you like to search for? Please choose only one.</div>
        <ul id="stores">
            <li>Store name 1:
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
            </li>
            <li>Store name 2:
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" />
            </li>
            <li>Store name 3:
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" />
            </li>
            <li>Store name 4:
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" />
            </li>
            <li>Store name 5:
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton5" runat="server" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Find locations" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <div>
            <iframe id="Map" runat="server"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;


public partial class WhereToBuy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Map.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Map.Visible = true;
        string zipCode = TextBox1.Text;
        string SearchURL = "";
        int store = 0;

        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            store = 1;
        }
        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            store = 2;
        }
        if (RadioButton3.Checked)
        {
            store = 3;
        }
        if (RadioButton4.Checked)
        {
            store = 4;
        }
        if (RadioButton5.Checked)
        {
            store = 5;
        }

        switch (store)
        {
            case 1:
                SearchURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=gnc+near%3A+";
                break;
            case 2:
                SearchURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=gnc+near%3A+"; //Change store name
                break;
            case 3:
                SearchURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=gnc+near%3A+"; //Change store name
                break;
            case 4:
                SearchURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=gnc+near%3A+"; //Change store name
                break;
            case 5:
                SearchURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=gnc+near%3A+"; //Change store name
                break;
            default:
                Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Select store", "<script>\n selectStore(); \n </script>"); //Rewrite flow to not load iframe if this executes... Back to new search...
                break;
        }

        Map.Attributes.Add("src", SearchURL + zipCode);
        Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Reload", "<script>\n reloadFrame('Map'); \n </script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the Google Maps API?  It's really nice.

Comment: Is it capable now of having a map embedded that allows you to search by zip code for any of a list of store names near there and doing it all on their end without a local database? If so that would be great but I didn't think it could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference to the GM api on text searching, particularly with "near",
    https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests

If you want multiple search results on a map, here is something you may need.
    [Google Maps Multiple Search Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013431/google-maps-multiple-search-results)

Good luck!